# Customize and change the default UI of pdftron- Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdftron

My question is does pdftron give Flutter developers ability to change the ui and add some button?
As an example, I want to swipe the pdf pages programmatically .
I couldn’t find any function help to move to next page , previous or jump to bookmark.

Comment: Are you currently working on iOS or Android?

Comment: Both iOS and Android

Comment: Hey, I am also working on pdftron? were you successful in customizing it in flutter?

Comment: yes, I added many new functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to navigate pages using the PDFTron Flutter library. To do this you would use [gotoPreviousPage](https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-flutter/blob/master/API.md#gotopreviouspage) and [gotoNextPage](https://github.com/PDFTron/pdftron-flutter/blob/master/API.md#gotonextpage).
If you want to add custom buttons you will have to fork the repo and develop these in native code.

Comment: I got it ...Thank you